# ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org port 22: Connection timed out fatal

Tags: ssh, push, bitbucket

Whole error is:

```
ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I'm getting this error when I do push from two of my projects which are on different servers (countries).

What could be problem?

UPDATE:

Using

```
ssh -v
```

I'm getting this:

```
usage: ssh [-somecode] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile]
           [-i identity_file] [-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport]
           [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S ctl_path]
           [-w tunnel:tunnel] [user@]hostname [command]
```

Comment: use ssh -v (or -vv, -vvv, ...)

Comment: @golimar - I'm connecting over ssh on mac mac through terminal.

Comment: so you are using the ssh command? then you should be able to do 'ssh -v'

Comment: What does do that command?

Comment: the program prints more information

Comment: @CroiOS he means use `ssh -v bitbucket.org`, or add more `-v` options. This is not a suitable SO question, though. and of course; you do have a configured `bitbucket.org` account?

Comment: @Petesh - Yes, everything works ok on my other sites which are connecting to bitbucket.

Comment: @CroiOS when I try to connect to bitbucket using an incorrect account/public key I see this issue. It is most likely a public/private key file issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check if you don't have iptable rules for ssh outgoing connections,
if true, add port 22.
For multiple ports:

```
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --match multiport --dport 22,1111,2222,3333 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: It did work for me but  can you please explain what this really does?

Answer (score 16):

**This may get it working again**

edit the ssh config file:

`nano  ~/.ssh/config`

make sure you have these lines:

```
Host bitbucket.org
 Hostname  altssh.bitbucket.org
 Port  443
```

Comment: That worked nicely. However I had to remove the backtick after the port number 443 (on MacOS).

Comment: Well spotted, that shouldn't have been in there, I have edited and removed it now, thanks

Answer (score -4):

check if bitbucket is down

1. Open Browser
2. Go to http://www.bitbucket.org
3. If the page doesn't display, it means bitbucket is down.

Solution: Wait for it :)

Comment: What if 3rd statement is false?

Comment: It would have been better to suggest checking their status page https://bitbucket.status.atlassian.com/