# Can't connect to BitBucket via ssh

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I'm having trouble with BitBucket. I've created my repo with:

```
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:bert_ramirez/hello_app.git
```

I then added the ssh key by first using `xclip -sel clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and pasting it into BitBucket.

When I try `git push -u origin --all` I am denied access with the following message:

> ssh: connect to host bitbuckey.org port 22: Connection refused 
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

I've followed through their BitBucket 101 and have no problem with GitHub, but so far no luck in my first attempts at BitBucket. Any hints?

Comment: tries with the solution given in this post
[ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org port 22: Connection timed out fatal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17826622/ssh-connect-to-host-bitbucket-org-port-22-connection-timed-out-fatal)

Answer (score 4):

`host bitbuckey.org port 22` could mean there is a typo.

It should be `bitbucket.org`, not `bitbuckey.org`.

You can change it easily with:

```
git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:bert_ramirez/hello_app.git
```

Comment: That was it! oh well...  learned how to remove a repository and add it back (correctly spelled!) Thank you!

Comment: @BertRamirez right, I have edited the answer to add the command changing the url associated to the remote '`origin`'.